# Tripura Rahasya. What is the general opinion?

Tags: shakti, shaktism

What is the opinion of this text? I am very interested in Shakti Sadhana. Would this text prove helpful?

Comment: i think it has more to do with vedanta than shakti sadhana. better to refer agamic texts like yogini hridayam

Comment: For Shakti upasana, Better to go with Tantric texts.